# DynamoDB Stream Lambda trigger not sending "INSERT" events to Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have a DynamoDB table with a stream enabled for NewImages to trigger a Lambda function. For some reason I am only seeing events trigger the Lambda with `eventName: "MODIFY"`, and no events with `eventName: "INSERT"` triggering the Lambda. I have Lambdas elsewhere that are creating new items via `DynamoDB.putItem`, which as far as I know should be triggering the Lambda with `eventName: "INSERT"`. Is `INSERT` only invoked by other actions? My DynamoDB table has 2 global secondary indexes if that is relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PutItem` will invoke an Lambda with `INSERT` if the item is a new item. If the item already existed, it will become invoke it with a `MODIFY`.

1. Check you are adding new data
2. Check you aren't using an event filter
3. Check you aren't filtering within the Lambda and missing `INSERT` events.

Comment: Yeah I was working too late last night.. the Lambda was in fact getting invoked with the `INSERT` events, there was an error elsewhere. Thank you for taking the time to answer and clarifying that the expected behavior is indeed that `PutItem` will invoke the Lambda with an `INSERT` if the item is new.